# Subscribe to Observable only after another Observable has received element

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm trying to declare all of my subscriptions in one place and without any intermediate relays or triggers. Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a `Signal<X>` which will start receiving values only after everything else is loaded and this thing works fine. But now I need to introduce another `Observable<Y>` which, when I subscribe, will start emitting values immediately because it's fetching data from DB. This is a bit problematic because my UI isn't yet ready to show the results and it'll only be ready when `Signal<X>` will emit its first value. After this I want to receive every single value `Observable<Y>` will receive.

I was trying with `skipUntil` and it's fine, but I'm losing the first element from `Observable<Y>`. `switchLatest` won't be a good match either. I was also looking into `amb`, but this won't give me the correct results either since it subscribes to both sequences and this isn't what I need.

My question is: Is there a possibility to subscribe to other Observable only after the original Observable has received one value? And also keep this subscription alive, so that it'll react to new values.

Comment: skipUntil does exactly what you need, what do you mean by you lose the first first element from Observable<Y>?

Comment: You aren't giving a whole lot of detail here. What does "after everything else is loaded" mean? Does it mean that X emits when viewDidLoad is called? What exactly is `X` and do you need it to create `Y`? Does `X` emit more than once? You say that `Observable<Y>` fetches values from a DB but then imply that it emits multiple times. Is this a local DB or off of a network request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a simple flatMap or one of its derivatives is all you need. A lot depends on how often X and Y emit and what you want to do when X emits after the first time.

You can learn more by reading [this article](https://medium.com/@danielt1263/rxswifts-many-faces-of-flatmap-5764e6c2018c), but the marble diagrams below are a decent summary (they assume the default "cold" or lazy observable. If `y` is hot then things are different.):

```
x.flatMap { _ in y }

x   +---1---2---3---|
y       +--A--B--C--|
y           +--D--E--F--|
y               +--G--H--J--|
--
    +------A--BD-CEG-FH--J--|
```

or

```
x.flatMapFirst { _ in y }

x   +---1---2---3---|
y       +--A--B--C--|
--
    +------A--B--C--|
```

or

```
x.flatMapLatest { _ in y }

x   +---1---2---3---|
y       +--A
y           +--D
y               +--G--H--J--|
--
    +------A---D---G--H--J--|
```

or

```
x.concatMap { _ in y }

x   +---1---2---3---|
y       +--A--B--C--|
y                   +--D--E--F--|
y                               +--G--H--J--|
--
    +------A--B--C-----D--E--F-----G--H--J--|
```

It all depends on what behavior your want exactly.

Comment: You were right. While I was looking for some sophisticated solution `dlatMapFirst` was exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you!